# fprintf macro with single param expecting ')'

Tags: c, macros

I got next debug macro, which works fine:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG

#define errorLog(fmt, ...) fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR %s: %d] " fmt "\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#endif
```

Except if i try next line (which produce **expected a ')'** error):

```
const char* someMessage = "Message";
errorLog(someMessage);
```

But this one produce no errors:

```
errorLog("Message");
```

Right now i solve this like:

```
const char* someMessage = "Message";
errorLog("%s", someMessage);
```

How to change macro to work with single `const char*` param as well?

```
const char* someMessage = "Message";
errorLog(someMessage); //fprintf(stderr, someMessage)
```

Comment: Try running the preprocessor on your code `g++ -S code.cpp`; it may help figuring out what the problem is.

Comment: Your macro uses `"[ERROR %s: %d] " fmt`. It will only work if `fmt` is a string literal. It is a good idea to separate format strings and actual messages, but if for some reason you don't want that, you have to make your macro contain *two* calls to `fprintf`, one to print the `ERROR: <function> <line>` part and the other to print everything else.

Comment: `##__VA_ARGS__` is a GCC extension, right?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, discussed [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written, your `errorLog` requires a string literal for the first (`fmt`) argument, as it tries to use string concatenation, which only works with string literals.  If you want a macro that can take any `char *`, not just a string literal, you have to use it directly, rather than pasting.  You could use something like:

```
#define errorLog(...)   \
        (fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR %s: %d] ", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__),  \
         fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__),  \
         fprintf(stderr, "\n"))
```

This will work for any `char *`, but will not have the same return value, if you care about that.  This also has the advantage that it doesn't depend on the gcc `, ## __VA_ARGS__` extension which may not work on other compilers.

If you want this to work properly in a multithreaded program, you might need:

```
#define errorLog(...)   \
        (flockfile(stderr),  \
         fprintf(stderr, "[ERROR %s: %d] ", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__),  \
         fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__),  \
         fprintf(stderr, "\n"),  \
         funlockfile(stderr))
```

instead